# IIS Forms Authentication Not Recognizing Cookie

Tags: iis, cookies, coldfusion, form-authentication

For some reason IIS is not recognizing my Forms Authentication cookie, it keeps redirecting to the login page. The login page is ColdFusion 10 based using .NET integration. I've basically tried to mimic the "Creating the Forms Authentication Cookie" section of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx).

IIS 7.5 Authentication has Forms Authentication enabled with these settings:

- Login URL: /my/login/page.cfm
- Timeout: 30
- Mode: Use cookies
- Name: .CFAUTH
- Protection: Encryption
- Require SSL: No
- Extend expiration: Yes

The code basically looks like this:

```
<!--- Authenticating code here... --->

<!--- Create .NET Instances --->
<cfobject type=".NET" assembly="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll" class="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication" name="authForm" />
<cfobject type=".NET" assembly="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll" class="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket" name="authTicket" />

<!--- Create Auth Ticket --->
<cfset authTicket.init(2, "user.name", Now(), DateAdd("n", 30, Now()), false, "") />

<!--- Encrypt the Ticket, Creating Cookie Value --->
<cfset authCookie = authForm.Encrypt(authTicket) />

<!--- Create the actual Cookie --->
<cfcookie name=".CFAUTH" expires="#DateAdd("n", 30, Now())#" value="#authCookie#" />

<!--- Redirect Back to Originating URL --->
<cflocation url="#URL.ReturnUrl#" />
```

I know everything with the code is working properly because the cookie *is* set in the browser *and* I can `Decrypt()` the cookie value and `Get_Name()` to retrieve the correct username. However, IIS just doesn't care about the cookie. Any thoughts? Am I missing something? Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: Ok, I have found an Application log event that relates: "Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid." So IIS is trying at least. I suspect this has to do with the Machine Keys used for Encryption, the ColdFusion Integration and IIS AppPool may differ. Now I just need to figure out how to verify and match them..

Answer (score 0):

Check your cookies again. ColdFusion capitalizes cookie names, regardless of how you type in the name. Also verify the domains. I've had issues previously with mixing CF and .Net where cookies were involved. We ultimately tracked the issue back to the capitalization issues and the cookie domain.

Grab a cookie plugin for your browser. Those are invaluable when hunting down cookie issues.